# When I click an item in ListView, I want to populate EditText with its values for updating in SQLite database

Tags: java, android

I am opening a new activity which uses `CursorLoader` to get data from local `SQLite` db. Whenever I click the listitem, for some reason it always populates the values from the first item. I want to populate the values for the specific list item I clicked. For eg: If I click "watch" item, it still populates "book" values in `Edittext`. Am I missing anything here?

[image: App Screenshot]

Here is my code for CursorLoader:

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {

    String[] projection = {
            ItemContract.ItemEntry._ID,
            ItemContract.ItemEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_NAME,
            ItemContract.ItemEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_QUANTITY,
            ItemContract.ItemEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_PRICE,
            ItemContract.ItemEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_IMAGE
    };

    return new CursorLoader(this, ItemContract.ItemEntry.CONTENT_URI,projection,null,null,null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {

    if (cursor == null || cursor.getCount() < 1) {
        return;
    }

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        int nameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ItemContract.ItemEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_NAME);
        int quantityColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ItemContract.ItemEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_QUANTITY);
        int priceColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ItemContract.ItemEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_PRICE);
        int imageColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ItemContract.ItemEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_IMAGE);


        String editCurrentName = cursor.getString(nameColumnIndex);
        int editCurrentQuantity = cursor.getInt(quantityColumnIndex);
        Float editCurrentPrice = cursor.getFloat(priceColumnIndex);
        String editCurrentImage = cursor.getString(imageColumnIndex);


        if(editCurrentImage != null) {
            editImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            editImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(editCurrentImage));

        }
        else {
            editImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        editName.setText(editCurrentName);
        editQuantity.setText(Integer.toString(editCurrentQuantity));
        editPrice.setText(Float.toString(editCurrentPrice));

    }

}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    Log.e("EDITACTIVITY", "onLoaderReset: ");
    editName.setText("");
    editQuantity.setText("");
    editPrice.setText("");
    editImage.setImageDrawable(null);

}
```

Comment: post your click list item code please !!

Comment: Why are you fetching the items from the cursor? Once you have updated the list view then on list item click get the data from the list item itself. And post on the method of onItemClick method.

Answer (score 0):

This will be an issue with how you retrieve the `Cursor`from the `ListView` or AnyView's position. The way to retrieve values from the `Cursor` you got from the `onItemClickListener` in the `ListView` or AnyView's itself:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long id) {
        //Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
       // Use the Cursor to retrieve the value from here!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are simple loading cursor, so without passing condition it will return all data and then also you are fetching first row data. So it will only return very first data in all scenarios.

**Solution**

In this case there are three solutions available which you can use.

**Solution1:**

When user click on item, at that time you can fetch the item object and pass the values to edit activity.

Something like this: [http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/04/start-new-activity-from-android-listview-onitem-clicked.html][1]

**Solution2:**

When user click on item, at that time fetch only the item id and pass to the edit activity. Now you have to pass argument as below in cursor loader.

```
// Here I am storing passed id in one variable, you have to set selected_item_id in intent while starting new activity
 int selectedId = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("selected_item_id",0);

 public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {

 String[] projection = {
        ItemContract.ItemEntry._ID,
        ItemContract.ItemEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_NAME,
        ItemContract.ItemEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_QUANTITY,
        ItemContract.ItemEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_PRICE,
        ItemContract.ItemEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_IMAGE
 };

 String selection = ItemContract.ItemEntry._ID + "=?";
 String[] selectionArgs = { String.valueOf(selectedId) };

 return new CursorLoader(this, ItemContract.ItemEntry.CONTENT_URI,projection, selection ,selectionArgs ,null);
}
```

Now, you will get actual result.

**In third solution you have to use your own method for loader and then in finished you have to fetch one by one cursor data and then match with selectedId.**

Last one is little bit complex and lengthy so try to use first or second only.